# relying on a stateful service for configuration values?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-service-fabric

We have approximately 100 microservices running. Each microservice has an entire set of configuration files such as applicationmanifest.xml, settings.xml, node1.xml, etc.

This is getting to be a configuration nightmare.

After exploring [this](https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/114), someone has suggested:

> You can keep configs inside stateful service, then change parameters
>   through your API.

The problem I see with this, is that there is now a single point of a failure: the service that provides the configuration values.

Is there a centralized solution to maintaining so much configuration data for every microservice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

**NOTE:** It seems your question is blurred between whether to use a **single configuration service is reliable** or whether to use **static vs dynamic configuration**.

For the debate on **static vs dynamic configuration**, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46967362/585968) to the [OP's other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46966601/configuration-transforms-in-service-fabric).

---

A config service sounds reasonable particularly when you consider that Service Fabric is designed to be realiable, even stateful services.

MSDN:

> Service Fabric enables you to build and manage scalable and **reliable** applications composed of microservices that run at high density on a shared pool of machines, which is referred to as a cluster
>
> Develop highly **reliable** stateless and **stateful** microservices.  [Tell me more...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-overview)

Stateful services store state in a [reliable distrubuted dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-quick-start#create-a-stateful-service) enclosed in a transaction which guarentees the data is stored if the transaction was successful.

OP:

> *The problem I see with this, is that there is now a single point of a failure: the service that provides the configuration values.*

Not necessarily.  It's not really the service that is the single point of failure but a *"fault domain"* as defined by Service Fabric and your chosen Azure data centre deployment options.

MSDN:

> A Fault Domain is any area of coordinated failure. A single machine is a Fault Domain (since it can fail on its own for various reasons, from power supply failures to drive failures to bad NIC firmware). Machines connected to the same Ethernet switch are in the same Fault Domain, as are machines sharing a single source of power or in a single location. Since it's natural for hardware faults to overlap, Fault Domains are inherently hierarchal and are represented as URIs in Service Fabric.
>
> It is important that Fault Domains are set up correctly since Service Fabric uses this information to safely place services. Service Fabric doesn't want to place services such that the loss of a Fault Domain (caused by the failure of some component) causes a service to go down. In the Azure environment Service Fabric uses the Fault Domain information provided by the environment to correctly configure the nodes in the cluster on your behalf. For Service Fabric Standalone, Fault Domains are defined at the time that the cluster is set up

So you would probably want to have at least two configuration services running on two separate fault domains.

### More

- [Describing a service fabric cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-resource-manager-cluster-description)

Comment: thank you very much for this thorough and insightful answer. my point is that if there's something wrong with the configuration provider service, the entire cluster is screwed. would you agree?  wouldnt you agree that allowing every service to have its own set of config files would be a significantly more robust solution? i'm playing devils advocate here

Comment: If you are only running a single instance of the Config service in a single fault domain and no where else; for your Azure subscription - _yes_.  But then, I would probably sack your Operations guy ;)

Comment: well i mean what if my service just has a bug on it, irrelevant how many instances of it are running

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' yes that would be unfortunate.  But then AD does a pretty good job as an example of being a repository for all things. :)

Comment: you mean AD is also a "single point of failure" yet it does a pretty good job?

Comment: can i ask for you to weigh in on this question as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46966601/configuration-transforms-in-service-fabric

Comment: absolutely. your answer is amazingly groovy. the reason im not accepting yet is just to solicit more opinions. good night for now

Comment: i would be very grateful if you could respond to what you think of the other answer

Comment: thanks so much!! would appreciate your suggestions here as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46996457/how-to-do-continuous-integration-with-service-fabric-with-tfs-2013

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' you are welcome good sir.   For the other question, I've not used TFS 2013 with SF on-premises or otherwise sadly.

Answer (score 2):

While a central configuration service seems like the way to do, if you do it you introduce a few problem that you must get right each time). When you have an central configuration service it MUST be updated with the correct configuration **before** you start your code upgrade and you must of course keep previous configurations around in case your deployment rolls back. Here's the configuration slide that I presented when I was on the Service Fabric team.

[image]

Service Fabric ships with the ability to version configuration, you should use that, but not in the manner that Service Fabric recommends. For my projects, I use the Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration for configuration. Capture the configuration events

```
            context.CodePackageActivationContext.ConfigurationPackageAddedEvent += CodePackageActivationContext_ConfigurationPackageAddedEvent;
        context.CodePackageActivationContext.ConfigurationPackageModifiedEvent += CodePackageActivationContext_ConfigurationPackageModifiedEvent;
        context.CodePackageActivationContext.ConfigurationPackageRemovedEvent += Context_ConfigurationPackageRemovedEvent;
```

Each of these event handler can call to load the configuration like this

```
        protected IConfigurationRoot LoadConfiguration()
    {
        ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();

        // Get the name of the environment this service is running within.
        EnvironmentName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(EnvironmentVariableName);
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(EnvironmentName))
        {
            var err = $"Environment is not defined using '{EnvironmentVariableName}'.";
            _logger.Fatal(err);
            throw new ArgumentException(err);
        }

        // Enumerate the configuration packaged. Look for the service type name, service name or settings.
        IList<string> names = Context?.CodePackageActivationContext?.GetConfigurationPackageNames();
        if (null != names)
        {
            foreach (string name in names)
            {
                if (name.Equals(GenericStatelessService.ConfigPackageName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    var newPackage = Context.CodePackageActivationContext.GetConfigurationPackageObject(name);

                    // Set the base path to be the configuration directory, then add the JSON file for the service name and the service type name.
                    builder.SetBasePath(newPackage.Path)                            
                        .AddJsonFile($"{ServiceInstanceName}-{EnvironmentName}.json", true, true)
                        .AddJsonFile($"{Context.ServiceTypeName}-{EnvironmentName}.json", true, true);

                    // Load the settings into memory.
                    builder.AddInMemoryCollection(LoadSettings(newPackage));
                }
            }
        }

        // Swap in a new configuration.
        return builder.Build();
    }
```

You can now interact with Configuration using the .Net configuration. Last thing to cover is the format of the configuration files. In the PackageRoot | Config directory, you simply include your configuration files. I happen to use the Name of the service + datacenter.
[image: Configuration Directory]

The files internal look like this, where there is a JSON property for each service fabric class.

```
    {
  "Logging": {
    "SeqUri": "http://localhost:5341",
    "MaxFileSizeMB": "100",
    "DaysToKeep": "1",
    "FlushInterval": "00:01:00",
    "SeqDefaultLogLevel": "Verbose",
    "FileDefaultLogLevel": "Verbose"
  },

  "ApplicationOperations": {
     "your values here": "<values>"
  },
```

If you stuck this long, the big advantage of this is that the configuration gets deployed at the same time as the code and if the code rolls back, so does the configuration, leaving you in a know state.

Comment: Nonsense, you are not answering the question.  If configuration really ought to be immutable then it wouldn't be in a separate file where it can be changed.  True immutable configuration would be explicit c# configuration statements like the difference between explicit WCF configuration c# code and WCF configuration in say **web.config** files.

Comment: _"creates an ordering for deployment"_ - that would apply too for configuration files which are now dependencies.  You cannot guarentee that the necessary config artefact is present in Production.  You also have a dependency I see in your `LoadConfiguration()` for `EnvironmentVariableName`

Comment: _"Issues with accessing remote store can cause your service to fail"_ - this is **Azure** and Service Fabric.  You should be placing **critical** services on **different fault domains**

Comment: The whole idea of placing configuration in config files gained momentum in IIS and later in IIS-hosted WCF services.  People loved it for convenience for on-the-spot configuration changes and how IIS automatically restarted the app/service.  However anyone serious about _immutable_ configuration would not utilise such a practice or any configuration artefacts or dependencies of any kind and instead, particularly for WCF, place said configuration explicitly in c# code. The same could be said for SF

Comment: @todd i'm going to assume that you agree with mickyd, since you are not answering?

Comment: Don't agree with MickyD at all, but he's entitled to believe what he wants. mickyd, service fabric ensures that the configuration files are on the node same as the code files, and my solution distributes all configuration files for all environments -- if you don't want the environment ability, remove it. Different fault domains don't matter if someone messed up the configuration in the central service.